# Set Task Queue Name using a formula in process builder

Tags: process-builder, formula, queue

I am listening to a custom object called LandingObject using process builder which generates a task and either assigns the task to a taskQueue or a person's ID. I would like to set the task 'Assigned To' field using a simple formula rather than creating (2) distinct decision node filters in process builder. One using the AssignedTo = queue. The other AssignedTo = userID.

Is there a way to set the queue name in a formula using this type of approach? I cannot seem to traverse to the task queue name.

If( (personNumber = null), set to a queueName), userID)

Comment: you need to assign to a Queue.Id, not name

Comment: But you cannot traverse to the que.id. Assuming the id of a  queue persist among all environs?

Comment: If the queue was first defined in production and you are using a sandbox then queueId is same.

Comment: It is instantiated first in a sandbox , then to a QA then to be released in production. Sounds like I need 2 separate filters for each use case if I can’t execute this in one simple formula.

Comment: You have options here: (1) put the queueId in a custom label and have your formula reference the custom label. This allows for different ids by org; 2) Have the PB invoke a Flow that does the Task creation; the flow can query on `Group` using the queue's DeveloperName, then the flow can assign the queueId to Task's assignedTo. I like option 2

Comment: Thanks cropredy. Agree.